# json4s: Convert type to JValue

Tags: scala, json4s

I have some source object `src` and would like to get a `JValue` from it. All the examples and documentation for json4s seem to revolve around getting a JSON-encoded string, like so:

```
def encodeJson(src: AnyRef): String = {
    import org.json4s.NoTypeHints
    import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
    import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

    write(src)
}
```

That's great if I only want the end result, but I'd prefer to write a:

```
def encodeJson(src: AnyRef): JValue
```

It seems like [`ToJsonWritable[T]`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ToJsonWritable.scala) is what I want to use, but I can't seem to find an implementation for `Writer[AnyRef]` (nor can I find scaladocs for json4s which would just tell me the implementations).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer here is `org.json4s.Extraction` -- it has a method `decompose(a: Any)(implicit formats: Formats): JValue`:

```
def encodeJson(src: AnyRef): JValue = {
    import org.json4s.{ Extraction, NoTypeHints }
    import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._
    import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

    Extraction.decompose(src)
}
```